# How to convert a pandas dataframe to a an arrow dataset?

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

In huggingface library, there is a particular format of datasets called arrow dataset

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html

https://huggingface.co/datasets/wiki_lingua

I have to convert a normal pandas dataframe to a dataset or read a tabluar csv file as a dataset.

Is that possible?

Comment: The word "dataset" is a little ambiguous here.  It appears HuggingFace has a concept of a dataset [nlp.Dataset](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v0.4.0/package_reference/main_classes.html#nlp.Dataset) which is (I think, but am not very sure) a single file.  You can create an `nlp.Dataset` from CSV directly without involving pandas or pyarrow.  Arrow also has a notion of a dataset (`pyarrow.dataset.Dataset`) which represents a collection of 1 or more files.  @TDrabas has a great answer for creating one of those.  You can also create a `pyarrow.dataset.Dataset` from CSV directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a `pyarrow.Table` and then convert it to a `Dataset`. Here's an example.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5]})
dataset = ds.dataset(pa.Table.from_pandas(df).to_batches())

### convert to Huggingface dataset
hg_dataset = Dataset(pa.Table.from_pandas(df))
```

To convert to a `Table` only you can use `from_pandas(…)` method as shown in the docs and the example above. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html

A reference to Huggingface docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes.html#dataset

Comment: In addition, the huggingface Dataset object seems to have a `from_pandas()` itself as well (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading.html#pandas-dataframe)

Comment: i want dataset not table. from_dataset converts dataframe into table. Or maybe you can tell how to convert table to dataset?

Comment: Aaah I missed that. Altered the answer.

Comment: it says its an pyarrow._dataset.InMemoryDataset whereas what wiki_lingua is, a 'datasets.arrows_dataset.Dataset'. How to convert the inmemory to the one i need?

Comment: I think @Pace is right and the word `dataset` here is loaded. BUT, you can take `pyarrow.Table` and pass it as a parameter to `datasets.Dataset` to convert it. Added another line there.